# Erro ao criar tabelas - ASPNET-CORE-C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, classes, asp-net-core, visual-studio-2019

Boa tarde a todos.
Estou estudando C# com Asp Net Core e estou com problemas em uma questão de um trabalho.
Preciso criar diversas tabelas (consulta, médico, paciente...) dentro do banco ConsultorioDatabase mas só aparece a tabela paciente e ao compilar o projeto e acessar a rota /Consulta aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro Apresentado]

Os códigos do projeto estão no seguinte repositório:
[SiteConsultório](https://github.com/JuliaMaglhaes/SiteConsultorio)

Comment: você adicionou uma nova migration depois que criou as outras entidades?

Comment: Testei aqui seu projeto e criou todas as tabelas. Você está utilizando que comando para criar as tabelas?